# Why does not work validation input in directive?

Tags: angularjs

I have written custom directive that check typing text in input field. And highlights the inputs where there is errors.

```
.directive('checkValueType', function () {
        return {

            restrict: 'E',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                ngModel: '='
            },

            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

                var status = false;

                var type_value = attrs.typeValue;

                ngModel.$validators.required = function(v) {

                    switch (type_value){

                        case "integer":
                            status = isInt(v);
                         break;
                    }


                    return status;
                };
            }
        };
    })
```

And I call this like:

```
<input check-value-type type-value="{{node.type_value}}" ng-model="node.value">
```

Comment: I tried to  make `console.log(type_value)` after `var type_value` it is silent

Comment: What error to you get? Also I would expect `restrict: 'A'`

Comment: When I added `EA` it works, but instead does not work bind to back element

Comment: I dont have any errors

Comment: It works, but if status is false, then model is not changed, how to fix it?